# Sort in mongoDB using aggregation for path missing in project clause

Tags: mongodb

Can I sort applications in mongoDB using aggregation without including the field i am sorting by in projection clause?
for example:

```
  db.MYDB.aggregate([{ "$match" : { "age" : { "$gte" : 18}}}, 
   { "$project" : { "name" : 1 , "familyName" : 1}}, 
   { "$sort" : { "age" : -1}}, 
   { "$skip" : 0}, 
   { "$limit" : 30}])
```

Comment: why do you want to remove age in projection stage if you want to perform sort in sort stag on age field?

Comment: Because this is simple example  for what I want to do, not the real case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Only `name` and `familyName` is passed from aggregation pipeline after `project` stag.
- You cannot perform a `sort` on `age` if it's not a part of aggregation pipeline any further. The sort operation on age field is simply ignored.